# split string with a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have some string something like this

```
string = "2001 data analysis /n python /n data mining /n data /n mining /n 2013 data .

extracting /n data analysis /n analysis /n"
```

I want to split string with four lines
output should be like this where starting of element is a year and after that 4 lines

```
list = ["2001 data analysis python data mining ", "2013 data extracting data analysis"]
```

Comment: have you tried regex?

Comment: @NiraliKhoda: `'\n'` **IS NOT ** `'/n'`

Answer (score 0):

The regex expression:

```
[0-9]{4}((?:(?!/n).)+(/n)){5}
```

should help split the strings in the way you want.

[0-9]{4} matches the year

(?:(?!/n).)+ matches everything but the "/n" sequence

(/n) matches the /n sequence

finally the last two are wrapped in (...){5} to match 4 lines